# Javascript: Change table row HTML

Tags: javascript, html, outerhtml

I'm creating a template for our companies quoting software, which generates a HTML page and populates a table dynamically with each quoted item being a new row.

I need to check for a specific part number within the quote, and if it's present i then need to change the HTML for that row.

Here's a snippet of the HTML

```
    <div id="line-items-section" class="section">
<table id="line-item-detail-table" class="table-001">
<tr>
    <!-- <th>
    </th> -->
    <th>
        QTY
    </th>
    <th width="70%">
        Item
    </th>
    <th>
        Unit Price
    </th>
    <th>
        Ext Price
    </th>
</tr>
[Begin_LineItem] [Begin_LineTypeProduct]
<tr id="canChange" class="row-product">
    <!-- <td class="col-option-box">
        [QV_OptionBox]
    </td> -->
    <td class="col-qty">
        [DI_QtyBase]
    </td>
    <td class="col-partnumber">
        [DI_ManufacturerPartNumber]
    </td>
    <td class="col-unit-price">
        [DI_UnitPrice:f=1]
    </td>
    <td class="col-extended-price">
        [DI_ExtendedPrice:f=1]
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="row-product-description">
    <!-- <td class="col-option-box">
        [QV_OptionBox]
    </td> -->
    <td class="col-qty">
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" class="col-description">
        [DI_Description]
    </td>
</tr>
[End_LineTypeProduct]
```

I then have this Javascript file:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("td.col-partnumber");
    for(var value of matches.values()) {
        //console.log(value.innerText);
        if (value.innerText == "SLAB KIT FORM") {
            var str = '<tr class="row-comment"><td class="col-qty"></td><td colspan="4" class="col-description">[DI_Description]</td></tr>';
            var Obj = document.getElementById('canChange');
            Obj.outerHTML = str;
        }
    }
```

I'm using querySelectorAll and the For loop to find the part number I want (I'm looking for 'SLAB KIT FORM').
Then using outerHTML to change the HTML.

This partially works.

The result is, the part number is found, but the code changes only the first row in the table... the table row I'm looking for could appear anywhere in the table (and even multiple times in the same table).

Essentially, I need to have this code target only the table row that contains the cell with SLAB KIT FORM

Comment: Please attach snippet

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that you have mutliple rows that follow the markup of the table row marked with `class="row-product"`?

Comment: @Barthy - The quote software will produce multiple table rows (class="row-product") - one table row per product. There could be one product on the quote, or 100 products on the quote. each one gets a new new table row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add the same id to each row. Once you have found the right table cell through javascript, you can find the appropriate row through the `parentNode` property.

For example like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const button = document.querySelector('.run-script')
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var matches = document.querySelectorAll("td.col-partnumber");
    for (var value of matches.values()) {
      // console.info(value);
      if (value.innerText == "SLAB KIT FORM") {
        var str = '<tr class="row-comment"><td class="col-qty"></td><td colspan="4" class="col-description">[DI_Description]</td></tr>';
        var Obj = value.parentNode;
        Obj.outerHTML = str;
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
button {
 padding: 1rem;
 background-color: darkred;
 color: white;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
 width: 25%;
 min-width: 200px;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}

table {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

table td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

table th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="run-script" type="button">Run Script</button>

<div id="line-items-section" class="section">
  <table id="line-item-detail-table" class="table-001">
    <tr>
      <!-- <th>
        </th> -->
      <th>
        QTY
      </th>
      <th width="70%">
        Item
      </th>
      <th>
        Unit Price
      </th>
      <th>
        Ext Price
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-product">
      <td class="col-qty">
        5
      </td>
      <td class="col-partnumber">
        NOT THE PARTNUMBER YOU'RE LOOKING FOR
      </td>
      <td class="col-unit-price">
        40
      </td>
      <td class="col-extended-price">
        forty
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-product-description">
      <td class="col-qty">
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="col-description">
        some description
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-product">
      <td class="col-qty">
        8
      </td>
      <td class="col-partnumber">
        SLAB KIT FORM
      </td>
      <td class="col-unit-price">
        20
      </td>
      <td class="col-extended-price">
        twenty
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row-product-description">
      <td class="col-qty">
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" class="col-description">
        other description
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Just remember that duplicate IDs were also kind of an issue here since they are invalid HTML.